# Showing alternate rows of one column to the other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
Vehicle Id  Arrival Time    Position
4              20              200
4              10              100
4              30              300
4              40              400
```

I want to arrange it like the one below:

```
Vehicle Id  Arrival Time    Start Position  End Position
4                10             100             200
4                20             200             300
4                30             300             400
4                40             400              --
```

I can solve the problem using `LEAD` function however I want to solve it using `ROW_NUMBER ()` and `JOIN` function.

I think `ROW_NUMBER ()` function will work like:

```
SELECT
   *, 
   ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle Id ORDER BY Vehicle Id, Arrival Time) AS RN 
FROM Table_name
```

But I am not to sure how I will use the `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can still have the same result with using `LEAD()` if you want to use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `Common table Expression`.

```
WITH recordList
AS
(
    SELECT  VehicleId, ArrivalTime, Position,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VehicleId, ArrivalTime) rn
    FROM    tableName
)
SELECT  a.VehicleId, 
        a.ArrivalTime, 
        a.Position StartPosition,
        b.Position EndPosition
FROM    recordList a
        LEFT JOIN recordList b
            ON a.rn + 1 = b.rn
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/429fef/4)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ VEHICLEID ║ ARRIVALTIME ║ STARTPOSITION ║ ENDPOSITION ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╣
║         4 ║          10 ║           100 ║ 200         ║
║         4 ║          20 ║           200 ║ 300         ║
║         4 ║          30 ║           300 ║ 400         ║
║         4 ║          40 ║           400 ║ (null)      ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
;WITH T as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by [Arrival Time]) RNum 
    from( 
        select 4 as [Vehicle Id], 20 [Arrival Time], 200 as Position union
        select 4 as [Vehicle Id], 10 [Arrival Time], 100 as Position union
        select 4 as [Vehicle Id], 30 [Arrival Time], 300 as Position union
        select 4 as [Vehicle Id], 40 [Arrival Time], 400 as Position
    )x
)
select 
    [Vehicle Id], 
    [Arrival Time], 
    Position as [Start Position], 
    (SELECT Position From T t2 WHERE t2.RNum=t1.Rnum+1)
from T t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use option with OUTER [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator with [ORDER BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) clause

```
SELECT t.VehicleId, t.ArrivalTime, 
       t.Position AS StartPosition, o.Position AS EndPosition
FROM dbo.test59 t OUTER APPLY (
                               SELECT TOP 1 Position
                               FROM dbo.test59 t2
                               WHERE t.VehicleId = t2.VehicleId
                                 AND t.ArrivalTime < t2.ArrivalTime
                               ORDER BY t2.ArrivalTime ASC
                               ) o
ORDER BY t.ArrivalTime
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9991f/1)